# Spring-boot 2.2.6.RELEASE Zuul not working

Tags: netflix-zuul

It seems that in 2.2.6 version of Spring Boot spring-cloud.version Hoxton.SR3 zuul is not recognized. 
I added it in the dependencies but its not compiled

this is my pom.xml:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And my code:

```java
package com.example.photoapp.api.gateway;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class PhotoAppApiZuulApiGateway2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PhotoAppApiZuulApiGateway2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Any idea what is the issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your cloud version:

```
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
```

to:

```
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
```